# Don't add to a list the same value

Tags: c#

I have a list of tickets.  Each ticket belongs to a single event.  I want create a list of all events from tickets.  I can get this list, but the same event (value) is repeated in the list. How can I ensure that an event is only added the list once?

```
 List<int> tickets = new List<int>();

 List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

 foreach (var s in tickets)
 {
     events.Add(_context.Event.Find(s));
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`List<T>.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method?

```
foreach (var s in tickets)
{
    var event = _context.Event.Find(s);
    if (!events.Contains(event))
    {
        events.Add(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If order of events is not important, you can use `HashSet<Event>` instead of List. That way event would not be added again if it already exists in the hash set. Also make sure that Event has overriden Equals and GetHashCode methods that compare actual properties of event.

Comment: One thing to note is that `HashSet<T>` is only available in .NET 3.5 and up.  You may want to add that disclaimer in your answer.

Comment: @JonSenchyna It would be uncommon (here on SO) to find someone not using at least .NET 3.5.  If that were the case, they would generally state so in the question itself.  On top of that, there is the non-generic `HashTable` even in .Net 1.0.

Comment: +1. `Dictionary` or `SortedDictionary` are 2.0 options... Explaining why using either of this structures instead of list should be done by OP as part of the homework assignment.

Comment: Regardless of how common it is, it's still a good idea to point it out.  Either way I gave this answer a +1, as it's a very good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

A full Linq solution with [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb338049.aspx):

```
var events = tickets.Select(ticket => _context.Event.Find(ticket)).Distinct();
```